# Close & Stop Playing Video

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm working on a Wordpress project that someone else coded, and am stuck on how to make the video associated with code below stop when it is closed via the animation. I've searched throughout the project but have been unable to locate and clarity what .api in this context is referring to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#view_video').click(function(){
    jQuery('.video_need').animate({
        height: 'show' 
    });
    jQuery('.video_need iframe').api("play");
  });
  jQuery('#close_video').click(function(){
    jQuery('.video_need').animate({
        height: 'hide' 
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: try this :http://jsfiddle.net/nkfH4/

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something along these lines.  Not sure what `.api()` is.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#view_video').click(function(){
    jQuery('.video_need').animate({
        height: 'show' 
    });
    jQuery('.video_need iframe').api("play");
  });
  jQuery('#close_video').click(function(){
    jQuery('.video_need').animate({
        height: 'hide' 
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      // animation completion callback
      complete: function() {
        jQuery('.video_need iframe').api("stop");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm stumped on the .api reference as well, as I have been unable to find anything related throughout the project.

Comment: Check to see what jQuery plugins are in the project. Probably some clues there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When I do a touch move on another video, the previous one doesn't stop playing, I can't fix it

```
            jQuery('.video-with-trailer').each(function(i, obj) {
      jQuery(this).on("touchmove", function() { hoverVideo(i); });        
      jQuery(this).on("scroll", function() { hideVideo(i); });
             });
    function hoverVideo(i) {
      var playPromise = jQuery('.wpst-trailer')[i].play();
      if (playPromise !== undefined) {
          playPromise.then(_ => {
          // Automatic playback started!
      // Show playing UI.
      // We can now safely pause video...
     /* video.pause();*/
      })
      .catch(error => {
      // Auto-play was prevented
      // Show paused UI.
      });
      }
    }
    function hideVideo(i) {
      //jQuery('.wpst-trailer')[i].currentTime = 0; 
      jQuery('.wpst-trailer')[i].load(); 
    }
```

Comment: Hello! If this is an issue please write it in comments and not in answer thanks!
Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer